# How to assign a footer in Delphi 11.1 to ListView when it is in dynamic appearance mode?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, footer

How to add a footer text to an FMX ListView when it is in dynamic appearence mode? I keep getting exception 20 or 80. I hope this is not a bug.

[image]
Please see the code below.

```
ListView1.Items.Clear; 
ListView1.BeginUpdate;
while not FDQuery1.Eof do
begin
  Item:=ListView1.Items.Add();
  Item.Tag:=FDQuery1.FieldByName('CustomerID').AsInteger;
           
  var LName    : TListItemText  := TListItemText(item.Objects.FindDrawable('Name'));
  LName.Font.Size:=12;
  var LCode    : TListItemText  := TListItemText(item.Objects.FindDrawable('Code'));

  var LImage1  : TListItemImage := TListItemImage(item.Objects.FindDrawable('Image1'));

  LImage1.ImageIndex := 0;

  LName.Text    := FDQuery1.FieldByName('Name').AsString;
  LCode.Text    := FDQuery1.FieldByName('Code').AsString;
  
    try
            Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
            Item.Text := 'TEST';
            Item.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Footer;
         except
            on E : Exception do
               ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' '+E.Message);
         end;       
  FDQuery1.Next;
end;

FDQuery1.Close;
FDConnection1.Close;
ListView1.EndUpdate;
```

Comment: What is "exception 20"? Delphi exceptions are not numeric values

Comment: I have edited my question with a screenshot and Footer part is in try , but this time I get expception 80. What do I do wrong. my ListView in Dynamic apparance mode it is somethig to do with it but what ?

Comment: When I try to add the footer as below I can see the footer text but not the fist one and finishes with C0 exception sometimes with different number.          
         Item2:=ListView1.Items.Add();
         var LName1  : TListItemText  := TListItemText(item2.Objects.Drawables[0]);
         Item2.Objects.DrawableByName('Name').Data := 'TEST'+IntToStr(i);
         Item2.Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Footer;
the problem is footer is ListHeader as apprance even if change it to customer text object is 'Text' but it works with exception error and not adding to the first item with the name 'Name'

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce (10.4.2 or 11.2)

[image: my test]

[image]

```
procedure TForm33.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var group : String;
begin
ListView1.BeginUpdate;
ListView1.Items.Clear;
FDQuery1.Open();

group:=Copy(FDQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_APPOSE').asString,1,1);
while not FDQuery1.Eof do
begin
  if (group<>Copy(FDQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_APPOSE').asString,1,1)) then
  begin
   with ListView1.Items.Add do
    begin
      purpose:=TListItemPurpose.Footer;
      text:='End Group '+Group;
    end;
   group:=Copy(FDQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_APPOSE').asString,1,1);
   end;

  with ListView1.Items.Add do
    begin
     TListItemText(Objects.FindDrawable('Code')).Text:=FDQuery1.FieldByName('CODE_APPOSE').asString;
     TListItemText(Objects.FindDrawable('Description')).Text:=FDQuery1.FieldByName('LIBELLE_APPOSE').asString;
     TListItemImage(Objects.FindDrawable('Image')).ImageIndex:=FDQuery1.RecNo-1;
    end;

  FDQuery1.Next;
end;
   with ListView1.Items.Add do
    begin
      purpose:=TListItemPurpose.Footer;
      text:='End Group '+Group;
    end;

FDQuery1.Close;
ListView1.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: Which mode your ListView appearance mode ? The problem  is in DynamicAppearance mode.

Comment: DynamicAppearance of course, as you asked. Answer updated.

Comment: my problem was using OnUpdateObjects event to arrange the position of the objects on the ListView programaticly. I have removed all my codes on that event and it worked. I dont know if I can manage without using that event. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After all I have figured out that DynamicApparance mode does not go well with OnUpdateObject event if we don't check the Objects. Finally, I can set Footer & Header text while changing the Font Size and with of the text object. Please see below the code.

```
procedure TFrmMain.GetCustomerList;
var
  Item : TListViewItem;
begin
      FDConnection1.Open;
      FDQuery1.Connection := FDConnection1;

      FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Customers';
      FDQuery1.Open;
      ListView1.Items.Clear;

      ListView1.BeginUpdate;

      while not FDQuery1.Eof do
      begin
           Item:=ListView1.Items.Add();
           Item.Tag:=FDQuery1.FieldByName('CustomerID').AsInteger;

           var LName    : TListItemText  := TListItemText(item.Objects.FindDrawable('Name'))   ; LName.Font.Size:=12;
           var LCode    : TListItemText  := TListItemText(item.Objects.FindDrawable('Code'))   ;
           var LAddress : TListItemText  := TListItemText(item.Objects.FindDrawable('Address')); LAddress.Font.Size:=11;
           var LCurrency: TListItemText  := TListItemText(item.Objects.FindDrawable('Currency'));
           var LImage1  : TListItemImage := TListItemImage(item.Objects.FindDrawable('Image1'));

           LImage1.ImageIndex := 0; 
           LName.Text    := FDQuery1.FieldByName('Name').AsString;
           LCode.Text    := FDQuery1.FieldByName('Code').AsString;
           LAddress.Text := FDQuery1.FieldByName('Address1').AsString.Trim; 
   
           with ListView1.Items.Add do
           begin
                purpose:=TListItemPurpose.Footer;
                text := 'TEST';
           end;
           FDQuery1.Next;
     end;
     FDQuery1.Close;
     FDConnection1.Close;
     ListView1.EndUpdate;
end;


procedure TFrmMain.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
   LName     : TListItemText ;
   LCode     : TListItemText ;
   LAddress  : TListItemText ;
   LImage1   : TListItemImage;
begin

   if AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Name') <> nil then
   begin
        LName     := TListItemText(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Name'));
        LCode     := TListItemText(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Code'));
        LAddress  := TListItemText(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Address'));
        LImage1   := TListItemImage(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Image1')) ;

        LName.Font.Size    := 13;
        LName.Width        := TListView(Sender).Width - LImage1.Width - 20;
        LAddress.Font.Size := 12;
        LAddress.Width     := TListView(Sender).Width - LImage1.Width - 20;
   end;
end;
```